# Create a summary report by summing the amount's of accounts with the same name and within the date range specified

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have heard from my friend that it is bad practice to normally loop though the whole database to meet certain criteria. He mentioned something about the proper way being that you index the objects of interest.

What I want to achieve here is make a report for our company. So I do this by summing up all the items that have the same account that is within the filter date range set by `start_date` and `end_date` to start.

Some variable definitions:

Account name: `data_entries.iloc[j, 4]`

Account type: `data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 1]`

Account amount: `data_entries.iloc[j, 5]`

So is there a more efficient way to write this code that will be less computationally taxing on the computer specifically. (minimize computational requirement)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

entries_csv = "C:\\Users\\Pops\\Desktop\\Entries.csv"
listofaccounts_csv = "C:\\Users\\Pops\\Desktop\\List of Accounts.csv"

data_entries = pd.read_csv(entries_csv)
data_listofaccounts = pd.read_csv(listofaccounts_csv)
data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date

summary_amount = [0]*(len(data_listofaccounts) + 1)
summary = (('DEBIT ACCOUNT', 'DEBIT AMOUNT'),)

start_date = datetime.date(2018, 4, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2018, 10, 30)

for i in range(0, len(data_listofaccounts)):
    for j in range(0, len(data_entries)):
        if start_date <= data_entries.iloc[j, 1] <= end_date:
            if data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 0] == data_entries.iloc[j, 4]\
                    and (data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 1] == "CURRENT ASSET" or
                         data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 1] == "FIXED ASSET" or
                         data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 1] == "EXPENSE"):
                summary_amount[i] += data_entries.iloc[j, 5]
            elif data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 0] == data_entries.iloc[j, 4]\
                    and (data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 1] == "CURRENT LIABILITY" or
                         data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 1] == "LONG TERM LIABILITY" or
                         data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 1] == "EQUITY"):
                summary_amount[i] -= data_entries.iloc[j, 5]
    summary += ((data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 0], "{:,}".format(round(summary_amount[i], 2))),)
```

Entries sample data:
[image]

List of Accounts sample data:
[image]

`List of Accounts` contains unique account names while in the `Entries` worksheet, it can be repeated.

Comment: How does this work: `data_listofaccounts.iloc[i, 1] == "CURRENT ASSET" or "FIXED ASSET" or "EXPENSE"`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 if the account type of row `i` which is located in the 2nd column equal to any of those 3 strings, it will be satisfied

Comment: @MarcSantos I'm not familiar with pandas, but in normal python; it would be represented as `<condition> or True or True`, which would always be `True` irrespective of the `condition` (which is `<value> == "CURRENT ASSET"`. Can you provide a link to docs where pandas mentions this behaviour of comparison?

Comment: @TobySpeight is that revision okay? I am not quite sure how to phrase my concern by stating what it does. Or should I just write down `create a summary report with criteria` or something

Comment: @hjpotter92 you're right it doesn't matter if it's in pandas. Sorry will revise this

Comment: @hjpotter92 I believe I already fixed it with the new edit.

Comment: This question would clearly benefit from a description of what kind of data are in the CSVs. From what I understand from the code, there seems to be descriptions of accounts (name, type…) in `List of Accounts.csv` and operations pertaining to those accounts (name of account affected, date, amount…) in `Entries.csv`. But it is hard to understand which informations are uniques and which can be repeated… A 10~30 line example for each CSV would be more than welcome.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Added in the main post

Comment: I’m still unsure of how things relate to each other, since I don't see anything in `Entries.csv` column E that matches `List of Accounts.csv` column A. Besides, does `List of Accounts.csv` column A contain duplicates or only unique values?

Comment: `List of Accounts.csv`'s column A contains unique values only. It's a one to many relationship to column E of `Entries.csv`. I'll update the photo in `List of Accounts.csv` to include the one in the sample sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of operation you’re doing is called [a join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html): you want to associate data from a `DataFrame` to data from another one based on a shared information on a given column.

To [join a `DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to another one or to a `Series`, you need to respect a simple rule: either you join on index or a column is joined to an index; and they must be of similar nature. So in your case, since you need to join on the name of the account, one of your `DataFrame` must be indexed by this name. Since it is its purpose, you need to reindex `data_listofaccounts` by its `'Account Name'` column:

```
data_listofaccounts = pd.read_csv(listofaccounts_csv)
data_listofaccounts = data_listofaccounts.set_index(['Account Name'])
```

Then, before joining, you can [filter out data that is out of your study range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates) so the join is performed on less data:

```
filtered = data_entries[(start_date <= data_entries['VOUCHER DATE']) & (data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] <= end_date)]
```

And thus the data you’re interested in is accessed using:

```
data_entries = pd.read_csv(entries_csv)
data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
data_listofaccounts = pd.read_csv(listofaccounts_csv)
data_listofaccounts = data_listofaccounts.set_index(['Account Name'])

start_date = datetime.date(2018, 4, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2018, 10, 30)
date_mask = (start_date <= data_entries['VOUCHER DATE']) & (data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] <= end_date)
interesting = data_entries[date_mask].join(data_listofaccounts, on='DEBIT ACCOUNT')
```

And then each row of `interesting` will have all the information needed: the transaction date, the name of the account, its type and the amount spent.

---

But this is all without taking into account the kind of operations you want to perform afterwards: [grouping by name and summing the amounts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). You can perform this operation directly before joining and it will simplify the process altogether:

```
data_entries = pd.read_csv(entries_csv)
data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y")

start_date = datetime.date(2018, 4, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2018, 10, 30)
date_mask = (start_date <= data_entries['VOUCHER DATE']) & (data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] <= end_date)

amount_per_account = data_entries[date_mask].groupby(['DEBIT ACCOUNT']).sum()
```

This will return a `DataFrame` indexed by the accounts names whose `'DEBIT AMOUNT'` column is the sum of each row pertaining to this account. You then just need to join with `data_listofaccounts` to know if this sum should be positive or negative based on the `'PARENT NODE'` column.

```
summary = data_listofaccounts.join(amount_per_account, on='Account Name', how='outer').fillna(0)
debit_mask = (summary.Type == 'CURRENT LIABILITY') | (summary.Type == 'LONG TERM LIABILITY') | (summary.Type == 'EQUITY')
summary[debit_mask]['DEBIT AMOUNT'] = -summary[debit_mask]['DEBIT AMOUNT']
```

---

Other improvements pertaining to coding style:

- you should define functions to organize your code
- you should guard your code using [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)
- you don't need to say that a variable contain some `data_`; same for namming a collection, you don't need to say what kind of collection hold the data (besides, in your case it is misleading as your `listofaccounts` is in fact a `DataFrame`); so `data_listofaccounts` => `accounts`
- you should follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) namming conventions

And to `pandas`:

- you can limit the amount of data retrieved from your CSVs by using the [`usecols`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) argument; this will lead to less data manipulation afterwards and thus more speed.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. What did you mean by `you don't need to say that a variable contain some data_`

Comment: @MarcSantos `data_something` => `something`

Comment: Btw, I get an error on this line `debit_mask = (summary.Type == 'CURRENT LIABILITY') | (summary.Type == 'LONG TERM LIABILITY') | (summary.type == 'EQUITY')`. The error message is `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'type'`. Did you mean `debit_mask = (summary['Type'] == 'CURRENT LIABILITY') | (summary['Type'] == 'LONG TERM LIABILITY') | (summary['Type'] == 'EQUITY')`.

Comment: @MarcSantos there is a typo, I wrote `summary.type` instead of `summary.Type`. Your version should work too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is my version and your version exactly the same? I never knew you could reference it they way you did

Comment: @MarcSantos Yes, for names that are valid Python identifiers, the attribute version return the same thing than the string key access. You are a tiny bit limited though, as you can't assign columns using this attribute notation.

Comment: Great. Never knew about that will read into it more